# need a driver for OKI B4100

Tags: 16.04, printing

I tried to use this file OkiB4100-hpijs.ppd, but seems not working, can see the printer but doesn't print, how to I troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

Download driver from my.okidata.com, it works good for Ubuntu 16.04 and other.

https://my.okidata.com/dsdownWeb.nsf/MOC-Lookup/90B6329133696B8585257A8000721484?OpenDocument